# Direct access to a second page behind a tableview

Tags: ios, tableview, key-value

I am developing an application for Iphone and I am a little lost with a particular case. This particular case is:

- I have a `NavigationViewController` with 3 tabs for example.
- On `tab 1` (called "tab1"), I have a value (value 1) in a field and a button `send`
- On `tab 2` (called "tab2"), I have a table view that displays a list of values. When I click on a row, a detail view (let's call it `detailview`) appears with the value and detailed information concerning this value.

Once I click on `send` on `tab1`, I would like my app to send the value to `detailview` without going through `tab2` table view. Then if I click on `back` on `detailview` I want to go back to `tab2` table view.

I attached a picture of the overall. I am totally new in Programming to if there is somewhere an example of code, I would appreciate.

thank you all for your help

cheers

Comment: You forgot the picture...

Comment: Wait, do you have a tabbarcontroller embedded in a navigation controller or the other way round?

Comment: If you understand the `delegate` pattern, that's probably your best bet. You also could have a try with `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: Hello, I cannot add the picture because I don't have 10 comments yet. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I have a tabbarcontroller only. I don't know how to embed a tabbarcontroller in a navigation controller.

Comment: What does the NSNotificationCenter do exactly ? I wish I could add a picture... you would understand immediately. can I send the picture to someone ?